# NullPointerException in getBinding when pressing back

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin

I build an app with multiple fragments and single activity. I have a detection fragment

```kotlin
private val PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
class DetectionFragment : Fragment(), ObjectDetectorHelper.DetectorListener {
    private var _binding: FragmentDetectionBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val TAG = "ObjectDetection"

    private lateinit var objectDetectorHelper: ObjectDetectorHelper
    private lateinit var bitmapBuffer: Bitmap
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null

    /** Blocking camera operations are performed using this executor */
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService



    private val requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { ...
            }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentDetectionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
        // Shut down our background executor
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        onBack()
        when {
            //checkpermission thing
        }
        objectDetectorHelper = ObjectDetectorHelper(
            context = requireContext(),
            objectDetectorListener = this)

        // Initialize our background executor
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        // Wait for the views to be properly laid out
        binding.viewFinder.post {
            // Set up the camera and its use cases
            setUpCamera()
        }

        // Attach listeners to UI control widgets
        initBottomSheetControls()
    }

    private fun initBottomSheetControls(){
        // When clicked, lower detection score threshold floor
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.thresholdMinus.setOnClickListener {
            if (objectDetectorHelper.threshold >= 0.1) {
                objectDetectorHelper.threshold -= 0.1f
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, raise detection score threshold floor
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.thresholdPlus.setOnClickListener {
            if (objectDetectorHelper.threshold <= 0.8) {
                objectDetectorHelper.threshold += 0.1f
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, reduce the number of objects that can be detected at a time
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.maxResultsMinus.setOnClickListener {
            if (objectDetectorHelper.maxResults > 1) {
                objectDetectorHelper.maxResults--
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, increase the number of objects that can be detected at a time
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.maxResultsPlus.setOnClickListener {
            if (objectDetectorHelper.maxResults < 5) {
                objectDetectorHelper.maxResults++
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, decrease the number of threads used for detection
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.threadsMinus.setOnClickListener {
            if (objectDetectorHelper.numThreads > 1) {
                objectDetectorHelper.numThreads--
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, increase the number of threads used for detection
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.threadsPlus.setOnClickListener {
            if (objectDetectorHelper.numThreads < 4) {
                objectDetectorHelper.numThreads++
                updateControlsUi()
            }
        }

        // When clicked, change the underlying hardware used for inference. Current options are CPU
        // GPU, and NNAPI
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerDelegate.setSelection(0, false)
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerDelegate.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                    objectDetectorHelper.currentDelegate = p2
                    updateControlsUi()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    /* no op */
                }
            }

        // When clicked, change the underlying model used for object detection
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerModel.setSelection(0, false)
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.spinnerModel.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                    objectDetectorHelper.currentModel = p2
                    updateControlsUi()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    /* no op */
                }
            }
    }

    private fun updateControlsUi() {
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.maxResultsValue.text =
            objectDetectorHelper.maxResults.toString()
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.thresholdValue.text =
            String.format("%.2f", objectDetectorHelper.threshold)
        binding.bottomSheetLayout.threadsValue.text =
            objectDetectorHelper.numThreads.toString()

        // Needs to be cleared instead of reinitialized because the GPU
        // delegate needs to be initialized on the thread using it when applicable
        objectDetectorHelper.clearObjectDetector()
        binding.overlay.clear()
    }

    // Initialize CameraX, and prepare to bind the camera use cases
    private fun setUpCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(
            {
                // CameraProvider
                cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

                // Build and bind the camera use cases
                bindCameraUseCases()
            },
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())
        )
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

        // CameraProvider
        val cameraProvider =
            cameraProvider ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera initialization failed.")

        // CameraSelector - makes assumption that we're only using the back camera
        val cameraSelector =
            CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

        // Preview. Only using the 4:3 ratio because this is the closest to our models
        preview =
            Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                .setTargetRotation(binding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
                .build()

        // ImageAnalysis. Using RGBA 8888 to match how our models work
        imageAnalyzer =
            ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                .setTargetRotation(binding.viewFinder.display.rotation)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
                .build()
                // The analyzer can then be assigned to the instance
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor) { image ->
                        if (!::bitmapBuffer.isInitialized) {
                            // The image rotation and RGB image buffer are initialized only once
                            // the analyzer has started running
                            bitmapBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                image.width,
                                image.height,
                                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                            )
                        }

                        detectObjects(image)
                    }
                }

        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()

        try {
            // A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
            // camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer)

            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }
    }

    private fun detectObjects(image: ImageProxy) {
        // Copy out RGB bits to the shared bitmap buffer
        image.use { bitmapBuffer.copyPixelsFromBuffer(image.planes[0].buffer) }

        val imageRotation = image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
        // Pass Bitmap and rotation to the object detector helper for processing and detection
        objectDetectorHelper.detect(bitmapBuffer, imageRotation)
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        imageAnalyzer?.targetRotation = binding.viewFinder.display.rotation
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onError(error: String) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    // Update UI after objects have been detected. Extracts original image height/width
    // to scale and place bounding boxes properly through OverlayView
    override fun onResults(
        results: MutableList<Detection>?,
        inferenceTime: Long,
        imageHeight: Int,
        imageWidth: Int
    ) {
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            binding.bottomSheetLayout.inferenceTimeVal.text =
                String.format("%d ms", inferenceTime)

            // Pass necessary information to OverlayView for drawing on the canvas
            binding.overlay.setResults(
                results ?: LinkedList<Detection>(),
                imageHeight,
                imageWidth
            )

            // Force a redraw
            binding.overlay.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this error when I press back button on this screen and immediately close the app.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: id.naufalfajar.go, PID: 5383                                                                                                                                                                                       
at id.naufalfajar.go.view.detection.DetectionFragment.getBinding(DetectionFragment.kt:34)
at id.naufalfajar.go.view.detection.DetectionFragment.onResults$lambda$14(DetectionFragment.kt:316)
at id.naufalfajar.go.view.detection.DetectionFragment.$r8$lambda$TqTYva0DaM8jzJqCVNkqO0J7EE4(Unknown Source:0)
at id.naufalfajar.go.view.detection.DetectionFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(Unknown Source:10)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

The error is in this line of code.

```
private val binding get() = _binding!! //DetectionFragment.kt:34

activity?.runOnUiThread {
  binding.bottomSheetLayout.inferenceTimeVal.text =
  String.format("%d ms", inferenceTime) //DetectionFragment.kt:316
...
}
```

My guessing is because I have a thread running on my background and when I press back, the binding is set to null.

Anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: If `binding` is null then you don't have a `TextView` to display anything on anyway. A quick solution would be to reference the nullable `_binding` instead, and null-check it before attempting to display your text. But probably a better idea would be to use a `ViewModel` to hold your UI state, and just update that with the text for display. That way you can observe it in `onCreateView`/`onViewCreated` and display whatever text is in there. If you have your views when the update happens, the text is displayed - otherwise it's deferred until the views are created

Comment: Yes I have try a null checking before I displaying the text like this and it works. Thank you, and maybe i'll try to use the ViewModel later.
activity?.runOnUiThread {
  if(_binding != null) {
    binding.bottomSheetLayout.inferenceTimeVal.text =
    String.format("%d ms", inferenceTime) //DetectionFragment.kt:316
    ...
  }
...
}

Answer (score 2):

It is expected to be `null` as you are explicitly setting it to `null` in `onDestroy`, Ideally you should cancel the background task when `fragment` is not `active` but in your case you could simply check `if(isAdded)` before accessing `binding` inside background task.

```
activity?.runOnUiThread {
  if(!activity.isFinishing() && isAdded) {
    binding.bottomSheetLayout.inferenceTimeVal.text =
    String.format("%d ms", inferenceTime) //DetectionFragment.kt:316
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I dont know how to stop the task. Instead I use checking for the binding 
```
activity?.runOnUiThread { if(_binding != null) { binding.bottomSheetLayout.inferenceTimeVal.text = String.format("%d ms", inferenceTime) //DetectionFragment.kt:316 ... } ... }
```
and it worked, but I still dont know if this is the right solution